# Unable to run os x lion on vmware workstation on windows 7

Tags: macos, osx-lion, vmware

I have a strange problem with running Mac OS X Lion or Mountain Lion on VMWare Workstation on my windows 7 PC.
Here is my hardware information, if it can help

```
Operating System      Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1.7600
CPU Type              QuadCore Intel Core i7-2600, 3500 MHz (35 x 100)
Motherboard Name      Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD5H
Motherboard Chipset   Intel Panther Point Z77, Intel Sandy Bridge
DIMM2: G Skill F3-12800CL8-4GBXM    4 GB DDR3-1600 DDR3 SDRAM
DIMM4: G Skill F3-12800CL8-4GBXM    4 GB DDR3-1600 DDR3 SDRAM
Video Adapter         ATI Radeon HD 4870 (RV770) 1024Mb
Disk Drive            ST3500418AS  (500 GB, 7200 RPM, SATA-II)
Disk Drive            ST500DM002-1BD142  (500 GB, 7200 RPM, SATA-III)
```

I have tried about 7 images of Mac OS X Lion and Mountain Lion on VMWare Workstation 8 and 9, and also tried to change almost all settings, but I cannot run it in any way. It shows grey screen with notice "VMWARE" and it's all, it seems there is nothing to be run, even it doesn't show the apple logo. It makes me mad for over 10 days, and I have no idea what else to do with this. I think, that the problem is in my hardware, because same image with same vmware is working very well on my HP probook 4530s.

Please, if everyone can help me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you can't run mac os x in vmware without using a side program to hack the source code of vmware and change stuff. It is also against the apple Terms of Service to run the mac os x operating system outside of an apple computer.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using a side program to hack the source code of vmware, and because of that it works on my Hp probook 4530s with windows 7. I need this for learning and studying ios development, then if I could, I will buy macbook, and sorry, but now I'm not ready to spend $2500 to buy something, which maybe I will not use.

Comment: Well either way we can't help you on here because it is technically illegal to do what you are doing. Have a good day and good luck with your ios studies.